# What is 〜からです and when is it used? How does it differ from 〜ですから and 〜んです?

Tags: grammar, translation, nuances, particle-から

I have seen this expression a few times, and have never quite understood it. In particular, it seems to be equatable both to ですから and to んです, but I can't figure out where it would be used over either of those two expressions. Here is an example I found on Google:

> 新聞{しんぶん}に目{め}を通{とお}していないと、仕事{しごと}が成立{せいりつ}しない**からです**。

<strike>I believe this translates to "Since I haven't been skimming the newspaper,  I do not have a job." (but I am not sure, and please correct me if I'm wrong).</strike>

What does the からです mean in this sentence? And more importantly, when is it appropriate to use, and how does it differ from ですから and んです?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> And more importantly, when is it appropriate to use,

Almost always, although it may sound a little bit informal.
When asked "なぜ" or "どうして", you'd answer with からです。

> なぜ遅れていますか？
>
> なぜなら、目覚まし時計が壊れていたからです。

(Why are you late? Because my alarm clock is broken)

> and how does it differ from ですから　and んです?

ですから is a connective, not a final part. "Aですから、B". If there's no B coming afterwards, then there's a problem. It's a bit like "since" in English. You don't just say "Since I like ice cream," but you say "(B) I bought an ice cream (A) since I like ice cream."

んです is "のです" used more colloquially.
It's like からです, and (in "のです" form) more formal. Also more common, as far as I can tell.

Comment: It is not true that a sentence cannot end with ですから.  See my answer for an explanation of why this happens, with an example.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: I can't help thinking it's not really a ending. To me, it's like saying "Because it is beautiful, you should see it (とても美しいですから、見るといいですよ)", but in a more oral fashion, where the justification comes after by pure effect of style. It's not "invalid" per say, it's just saying "B. Aですから" instead of 'normal' "Aですから、B".

Comment: I think that you are right, or at least I share the same feeling after reading your comment.  The construct like 見るといいですよ。とても美しいですから。 should be considered as [anastrophe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anastrophe); see also [this question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5605/varying-word-order-for-stylistic-effect).

Answer (score 10):

Your translation is not correct.  It seems that there are a few misunderstandings involved here.

First, “AとB” here means “B if A.”  仕事が成立しない means “I cannot do my job.”

> 新聞に目を通していないと、仕事が成立しない。  I cannot do my job without skimming the newspaper.

Next, ～から means “because ….”  Therefore, your sentence is

> 新聞に目を通していないと、仕事が成立しないからです。  It is because I cannot do my job without skimming the newspaper.

Note that the whole sentence has the form Xです, where X = 新聞に目を通していないと、仕事が成立しないから.  The subject of Xです is not stated, but for example the whole sentence can be a reply to a question “Why do you subscribe to a newspaper?”

As you can see, ～からです is used to state a reason for something.

> お菓子を食べたのは、おなかがすいていたからです。  The reason I ate snacks is because I was hungry.
>
> A: どうしてお菓子を食べたのですか。  Why did you eat snacks?
> B: おなかがすいていたからです。  Because I was hungry.

In colloquial context, です is often omitted.  In this case, we can use polite form before から.

> A: どうしてお菓子を食べたのですか。  Why did you eat snacks?
> B: おなかがすいていたから。 / おなかがすいていましたから。  Because I was hungry.

If the clause before から is a sentence ending with an adjective or a copula, its polite form ends with です, and you will end up with ですから.

> 函館山からの夜景を見るといいですよ。とても美しいですから。  You should see the night view from Mt. Hakodate.  (This is because) it is very beautiful.

んです does not state that it is a reason.  Depending on context, it can sometimes replace からです, though.

> A: どうしてお菓子を食べたのですか。  Why did you eat snacks?
> B: おなかがすいていたんです。  (Because) I was hungry.

Here おなかがすいていたんです literally just means “I was hungry,” but from the context, it is clear that it is stated as a reason why B ate snacks.