# Why does the sentence combination 「situation。 explanation から。」sound awkward?

Tags: grammar, particle-から

I'm Japanese giving advice to my friend.

He wrote two sentences like this:

> 昨日は寝れませんでした。気分が悪かった**ですから**。

According to a textbook「〜ですから。」is correct, but for me 「〜からです。」sounds better than「〜ですから。」

I couldn't find out when 「〜からです。」is better to use.

Can anyone tell me where to place 〜からです or 〜ですから in different grammatical situations?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/6904/1478

Comment: Thanks for information. I still can't get the rule of it though. I can't agree the answer `its polite form ends with です`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it has something to do with the proceeding sentence.

If you compare 「昨日は寝れませんでした。」 to 「函館山からの夜景を見るといいですよ。」 (from the example referenced in Enno's post), the latter is a suggestion, while the former is a fact.

Making up some other examples with "suggestions", 「彼と会ったほうがいいと思いますよ。とてもいい人ですから。」 and 「その授業は取らないほうがいいと思いますよ。先生がとても怖い人ですから。」 seem fine as well.

「勝訴すると思います。彼は一流の弁護士ですから。」 and 「まだ就労経験はありません。学生ですから。」, on the other hand, sound arrogant or mocking. Which sometimes could be an intended nuance, like 「僕は一流企業に就職できると思います。東大生ですから。」 or something, but generally seems like something to be avoided.

I'm not sure whether a "suggestion"-type leading sentence is the only kind which makes it natural to use a 〜ですから sentence without the ironic overtone, but I couldn't think of any other types.

Answer (score 1):

I really like Darius's observation about suggestion vs. fact, and that certainly has something to do with it, but I think there is also another reason for it being weird.

A lot of the awkwardness comes from the “悪**かったですから**”, rather than just the “ですから”. For example, it doesn't sound as weird when you tweak it to avoid making a `〜かったですから`:

> - 昨日は寝れませんでした。気分が悪かった**もの**ですから。
> - 昨日は寝れませんでした。気分が**すぐれませんでした**から。
> - 昨日は寝れませんでした。気分が**最悪でした**から。

Statements that end in `〜かったですから` actually all sound a little awkward, whether it follows a suggestion or a fact.

> - ぜひ夜景を見てください。私が見たときはとても美し**かったですから**。 ← ?
> - ぜひ夜景を見てください。私が見たときはとても**きれいでしたから**。 ← Better
> - 寝坊してしまいました。とても眠**かったですから**。 ← ?
> - 寝坊してしまいました。とても眠かった**もの**ですから。 ← Better

When you invert the clauses, you can clearly see how clumsy the `〜かったですから` is:

> - 忙し**かったですから**、行けませんでした。 ← Bad
> - 忙し**かったから**、行けませんでした。 ← OK
> - 多忙**でしたから**、行けませんでした。 ← OK

Comment: 凄まじい言語感覚やな。太刀打ちできひんわ。

Comment: @l'électeur 京都弁なのもあって皮肉られてるのか褒められてるのか本気でわかりません……

Comment: 最大の賛辞です。私自身は、この質問に対する良い回答は思いつきませんでした。今日になって、D.J.の回答を読み、感心して即UVしました。そしたら次にmirkaさんが回答されて、更に驚きUVしました。同時に、自身の知識・センスのなさに改めて愕然とした次第です。表現が誤解を招いたとしたら残念です。既に事実上SEを卒業した立場の者です。ネガティブな記憶が何もないMirkaさんに対し、皮肉を言いに戻ってくることはあり得ませんのでご安心ください。

Comment: @l'électeur ありがとうございます。こちらこそすみません、京都人への個人的な恐怖心からくる被害妄想でした。方言ひとつでここまでビビるなんて。いつも手探りで書いてるだけなので、何か間違った点があればどんどん指摘してくださいね。

Comment: Nice! This explains why the original sentence sounds ungrammatical as opposed to just having weird nuance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a tad archaic. For example this sentence given in a related SE answer:

> 函館山からの夜景を見るといいですよ。とても美しいですから。

Is definitely a common pattern you'll see in novels etc., but not many people actually talk like this.

I'd even argue `昨日は寝れませんでした。気分が悪かったからです。` sounds equally overly fancy; in that situation I'd say `昨日は寝れませんでした。気分が悪かったので。` or `昨日は寝れませんでした。気分が悪くて。`.

In a different situation, e.g. `熊は川に向かいます。サケが遡って来ることを知っているからです。` it's no longer weird because it's an appropriate situation to be fancy.

Comment: Ekhm. First paragraph contains an answer "it feels archaic", good, but the following three bear little relation to the question.

Comment: I agree that the sentence are old-fashioned. it's used only in  literary style. But what I want to know is difference between 〜からです or 〜ですから. Of course I can easily tell which one is suitable a specific sentence, but I could figure out basic rule of it.

Comment: Unlike what you said, ですから is certainly used very often in daily life. Its meaning is identical to だから.

Comment: @Yuu I imagine both Enno and ironsand know what is and isn't used in daily life, given that they're both native speakers of Japanese. And, FWIW, this answer says "*it* is just a tad archaic", and I'm pretty sure "it" is referring to "ですから in this sentence" not "ですから always".

Comment: @DariusJahandarie It doesn't matter whether they're native or not. I'm not telling them whether it is right or wrong. I felt the need to comment lest someone refers to this answer in the future and becomes mistaken. Even if you're sure, can you say the same for a random user who visits the site? It is not stated specifically in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

気分が悪かったですから, 昨日は寝れませんでした。
You are just stating your reason.

からです is used when you are emphasizing your reason when e.g asked about it or you have to explain it.
For example

Q.なぜ昨日寝れなかった？
A.気分が悪かったからだ。
or more better
気分が悪かったのだ。

Answer (score 0):

A purely grammatical difference that I noticed is that they can have different meanings.

The から in ですから always means "because," but the から in からです can mean different things based on what comes before it.

For example:

> 彼はアメリカからです。 He is from America.
>   授業は８時からです。 Class is from 8:00 onward.
>   夏休みは６月からです。 Summer vacation starts in June.
>   手紙は先生からです。 The letter is from the teacher.

ですから and だから help make it clearer that から is not being used in a situation like one of the above. In my opinion, they also sound more natural.